# set Enums using reflection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

How to set  Enums using reflection,

my class have enum :

```
public enum LevelEnum
    {
        NONE,
        CRF,
        SRS,
        HLD,
        CDD,
        CRS
    };
```

and in runtime I want to set that enum to CDD for ex.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Present your real problem and it would be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyObject
{
    public LevelEnum MyValue {get;set,};
}


var obj = new MyObject();
obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyValue").SetValue(LevelEnum.CDD, null);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try use of class Enum

```
LevelEnum s = (LevelEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(LevelEnum), "CDD");
```

Comment: And what could I do if `LevelEnum` were not available in immediate code but only via reflection, too?

Answer (score 2):

```
value = (LevelEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(LevelEnum),"CDD");
```

So basically you just parse the string corresponding to the enum value that you wish to assign to the variable. This will blow if the string is not a defined member of the enum. you can check that with `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LevelEnum),input);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I got error: it can't convert type LevelEnum  to String.

Comment: @Yasser nothing in the code above tries to convert LevelEnum to string