# Using Reflections i need to set value from ENums

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enums which is specified below

```
  public enum AdvisorType {

    CAB,

    LA,


    RSL,
}
```

My calling XML would be like this

```
<AdvisorType>CAB</AdvisorType>.
```

I have a parser which would set values for this object. I know serialization is easy but i am not doing serialization.

```
if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                                {
                                    object o1 = Convert.ChangeType(childElement.Value, typeof(Object));
                                    Object valueSet = Enum.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, o1);
                                    prop.SetValue(obj, valueSet, null);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(childElement.Value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                                    break;
                                }
```

Enum.Toobject is throwing an exception as "The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.".

Comment: possible duplicate of [set Enums using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009958/set-enums-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it like this and it works

```
if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                                {
                                    Object valueSet = Enum.Parse(prop.PropertyType, childElement.Value, true);
                                    prop.SetValue(obj, valueSet, null);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(childElement.Value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                                    break;
                                }
```